# NSubstitute clearing When().Do()

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

Is it possible with NSubstitute to clear or remove a previous .When().Do() configuration?

```
substitute.When(s => s.Method(1)).Do(c => { /* do something */ });
// code

substitute.When(s => s.Method(1)).Clear(); // <-- is this possible?
substitute.When(s => s.Method(1)).Do(c => { /* do something different */ });
// other code
```

Comment: First time, I voted to close my own question :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/master/Source/NSubstitute/Core/CallActions.cs) for the `CallActions`, there doesn't appear to be a way to remove or replace a callback.

Using an example proving the lack of *replace* functionality

```
int state = 0;
var substitute = Substitute.For<IFoo>();

substitute.When(s => s.Bar()).Do(c => state++);
substitute.Bar();
Assert.That(state, Is.EqualTo(1));

substitute.When(s => s.Bar()).Do(c => state--);
substitute.Bar();

// FAIL: Both Do delegates are executed and state == 1
Assert.That(state, Is.EqualTo(0));
```

where `IFoo` is

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
```

Lacking a change to the NSubstitute API, a workaround is:

```
var state = 0;
var substitute = Substitute.For<IFoo>();

Action<CallInfo>[] onBar = {c => state++};

substitute.When(s => s.Bar()).Do(c => onBar[0](c));
substitute.Bar();
Assert.That(state, Is.EqualTo(1));

onBar[0] = c => state--;
substitute.Bar();
Assert.That(state, Is.EqualTo(0));
```

Comment: Why does onBar need to be an array with a single element? Has this to do with closures?

Comment: Yes. This is one way around a modified closure. The dupe question you point to above does this with a class + property. This is slightly less code with the effect of diminished readability.

Comment: but I could also use a property on the class itself, then referencing it with `this.onBar`, right? I just can't use local variables.

Comment: Yes, `this.onBar` would also work. Essentially, to avoid the closure limitation, you need to provide a pointer-to-a-pointer.